# Error load data Jtable from MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I read this article about jtable with mvc at [codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=277576&av=419297](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=277576&av=419297)

I try it. But when run , i get error `An error occured while communicating to the server.`
Please see my code . In controller

```
   [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LocalList(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
        {
            try
            {
                string localCount = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select Count(*) FROM Location").ToString();
                IEnumerable<LOCATION> query = db.LOCATIONs;
                if (jtSorting.Equals("LOCATION_ID ASC"))
                {
                    query = db.LOCATIONs.OrderBy(e => e.LOCATION_ID).Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    query = db.LOCATIONs.OrderBy(e => e.LOCATION_ID).Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList();
                }
                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = query, TotalRecordCount = int.Parse(localCount) });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

And in View

```
$('#div_local').jtable({
            title: 'List Location',
            paging: true, //Enable paging
            pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
            sorting: true, //Enable sorting
            defaultSorting: 'LOCATION_ID ASC', //Set default sorting
            actions: {
                listAction: 'HomeController/LocalList'
            },
            fields: {
                AREA_ID: {
                    key: false,
                    list: false,
                    create: false
                },
                LOCATION_ID: {
                    key: true,
                    list: false,
                    create: false
                },
                LOCATION_NAME: {
                    title: 'Name'
                },
                LOCATION_DES: {
                    title: 'Des'
                }
            }
        });

        $('#div_local').jtable('load');
```

In here , all file script and stylesheet is ok. When i see log in chrome , i found

```
Request URL:http://localhost:27508/HomeController/LocalList?jtStartIndex=0&jtPageSize=10&jtSorting=LOCATION_ID%20ASC
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Can you tell me what mistake or wrong occurs in here ? and how to fix it.
Thank guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded as follow

1) Remove `[HttpPost]`

2) Edit listAction `listAction: 'Home/LocalList'`

It's work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the listAction is pointing to a non existing url (due to the HTTP-error 404).

Are you able to manually download the json using the request url you found in the log?

Comment: Dear user145689 , In HomeController, I have created View LocalList, then I tried `http: // localhost / home / LocalList` but get error `Server Error in '/' Application.The resource can not be found.`